# Multidimensional, get info from parent searching the child array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array that I am struggling with. The array is this:

```
$array => Array (1)
(
|    ['WHMCSAPI'] => Array (6)
|    (
|    |    ['ACTION'] = String(9) "getorders"
|    |    ['RESULT'] = String(7) "success"
|    |    ['TOTALRESULTS'] = String(1) "4"
|    |    ['STARTNUMBER'] = String(1) "0"
|    |    ['NUMRETURNED'] = String(1) "4"
|    |    ['ORDERS'] => Array (4)
|    |    (
|    |    |    ['ORDER'] => Array (27)
|    |    |    (
|    |    |    |    ['ID'] = String(3) "190"
|    |    |    |    ['ORDERNUM'] = String(10) "8782265746"
|    |    |    |    ['USERID'] = String(2) "66"
|    |    |    |    ['CONTACTID'] = String(1) "0"
|    |    |    |    ['DATE'] = String(19) "2013-12-31 16:00:42"
|    |    |    |    ['NAMESERVERS'] = NULL(0) NULL
|    |    |    |    ['TRANSFERSECRET'] = NULL(0) NULL
|    |    |    |    ['RENEWALS'] = NULL(0) NULL
|    |    |    |    ['PROMOCODE'] = NULL(0) NULL
|    |    |    |    ['PROMOTYPE'] = NULL(0) NULL
|    |    |    |    ['PROMOVALUE'] = NULL(0) NULL
|    |    |    |    ['ORDERDATA'] = String(6) "a:0:{}"
|    |    |    |    ['AMOUNT'] = String(4) "4.00"
|    |    |    |    ['PAYMENTMETHOD'] = String(9) "authorize"
|    |    |    |    ['INVOICEID'] = String(1) "0"
|    |    |    |    ['STATUS'] = String(6) "Active"
|    |    |    |    ['IPADDRESS'] = String(12) "64.50.180.53"
|    |    |    |    ['FRAUDMODULE'] = NULL(0) NULL
|    |    |    |    ['FRAUDOUTPUT'] = NULL(0) NULL
|    |    |    |    ['NOTES'] = NULL(0) NULL
|    |    |    |    ['PAYMENTMETHODNAME'] = String(11) "Credit Card"
|    |    |    |    ['PAYMENTSTATUS'] = NULL(0) NULL
|    |    |    |    ['NAME'] = String(11) "Chad Riddle"
|    |    |    |    ['CURRENCYPREFIX'] = String(1) "$"
|    |    |    |    ['CURRENCYSUFFIX'] = String(4) " USD"
|    |    |    |    ['FRAUDDATA'] = NULL(0) NULL
|    |    |    |    ['LINEITEMS'] => Array (1)
|    |    |    |    (
|    |    |    |    |    ['LINEITEM'] => Array (8)
|    |    |    |    |    (
|    |    |    |    |    |    ['TYPE'] = String(7) "product"
|    |    |    |    |    |    ['RELID'] = String(3) "488"
|    |    |    |    |    |    ['PRODUCTTYPE'] = String(21) "Other Product/Service"
|    |    |    |    |    |    ['PRODUCT'] = String(46) "SecureLive Addons - SecureLive Addon Domain 10"
|    |    |    |    |    |    ['DOMAIN'] = String(17) "2kplusgateway.org"
|    |    |    |    |    |    ['BILLINGCYCLE'] = String(7) "Monthly"
|    |    |    |    |    |    ['AMOUNT'] = String(9) "$4.00 USD"
|    |    |    |    |    |    ['STATUS'] = String(6) "Active"
|    |    |    |    |    )
|    |    |    |    )
|    |    |    )
|    |    |    ['ORDER1'] => Array (27)
|    |    |    (
|    |    |    |    ['ID'] = String(3) "189"
|    |    |    |    ['ORDERNUM'] = String(10) "6062113947"
|    |    |    |    ['USERID'] = String(2) "66"
|    |    |    |    ['CONTACTID'] = String(1) "0"
|    |    |    |    ['DATE'] = String(19) "2013-12-31 16:00:38"
|    |    |    |    ['NAMESERVERS'] = NULL(0) NULL
|    |    |    |    ['TRANSFERSECRET'] = NULL(0) NULL
|    |    |    |    ['RENEWALS'] = NULL(0) NULL
|    |    |    |    ['PROMOCODE'] = NULL(0) NULL
|    |    |    |    ['PROMOTYPE'] = NULL(0) NULL
|    |    |    |    ['PROMOVALUE'] = NULL(0) NULL
|    |    |    |    ['ORDERDATA'] = String(6) "a:0:{}"
|    |    |    |    ['AMOUNT'] = String(4) "4.00"
|    |    |    |    ['PAYMENTMETHOD'] = String(9) "authorize"
|    |    |    |    ['INVOICEID'] = String(1) "0"
|    |    |    |    ['STATUS'] = String(6) "Active"
|    |    |    |    ['IPADDRESS'] = String(12) "64.50.180.53"
|    |    |    |    ['FRAUDMODULE'] = NULL(0) NULL
|    |    |    |    ['FRAUDOUTPUT'] = NULL(0) NULL
|    |    |    |    ['NOTES'] = NULL(0) NULL
|    |    |    |    ['PAYMENTMETHODNAME'] = String(11) "Credit Card"
|    |    |    |    ['PAYMENTSTATUS'] = NULL(0) NULL
|    |    |    |    ['NAME'] = String(11) "Chad Riddle"
|    |    |    |    ['CURRENCYPREFIX'] = String(1) "$"
|    |    |    |    ['CURRENCYSUFFIX'] = String(4) " USD"
|    |    |    |    ['FRAUDDATA'] = NULL(0) NULL
|    |    |    |    ['LINEITEMS2'] => Array (1)
|    |    |    |    (
|    |    |    |    |    ['LINEITEM3'] => Array (8)
|    |    |    |    |    (
|    |    |    |    |    |    ['TYPE'] = String(7) "product"
|    |    |    |    |    |    ['RELID'] = String(3) "487"
|    |    |    |    |    |    ['PRODUCTTYPE'] = String(21) "Other Product/Service"
|    |    |    |    |    |    ['PRODUCT'] = String(46) "SecureLive Addons - SecureLive Addon Domain 10"
|    |    |    |    |    |    ['DOMAIN'] = String(11) "jbrowns.com"
|    |    |    |    |    |    ['BILLINGCYCLE'] = String(7) "Monthly"
|    |    |    |    |    |    ['AMOUNT'] = String(9) "$4.00 USD"
|    |    |    |    |    |    ['STATUS'] = String(6) "Active"
|    |    |    |    |    )
|    |    |    |    )
|    |    |    )
|    |    |    ['ORDER4'] => Array (27)
|    |    |    (
|    |    |    |    ['ID'] = String(3) "188"
|    |    |    |    ['ORDERNUM'] = String(10) "2178188116"
|    |    |    |    ['USERID'] = String(2) "66"
|    |    |    |    ['CONTACTID'] = String(1) "0"
|    |    |    |    ['DATE'] = String(19) "2013-12-31 16:00:34"
|    |    |    |    ['NAMESERVERS'] = NULL(0) NULL
|    |    |    |    ['TRANSFERSECRET'] = NULL(0) NULL
|    |    |    |    ['RENEWALS'] = NULL(0) NULL
|    |    |    |    ['PROMOCODE'] = NULL(0) NULL
|    |    |    |    ['PROMOTYPE'] = NULL(0) NULL
|    |    |    |    ['PROMOVALUE'] = NULL(0) NULL
|    |    |    |    ['ORDERDATA'] = String(6) "a:0:{}"
|    |    |    |    ['AMOUNT'] = String(4) "4.00"
|    |    |    |    ['PAYMENTMETHOD'] = String(9) "authorize"
|    |    |    |    ['INVOICEID'] = String(1) "0"
|    |    |    |    ['STATUS'] = String(6) "Active"
|    |    |    |    ['IPADDRESS'] = String(12) "64.50.180.53"
|    |    |    |    ['FRAUDMODULE'] = NULL(0) NULL
|    |    |    |    ['FRAUDOUTPUT'] = NULL(0) NULL
|    |    |    |    ['NOTES'] = NULL(0) NULL
|    |    |    |    ['PAYMENTMETHODNAME'] = String(11) "Credit Card"
|    |    |    |    ['PAYMENTSTATUS'] = NULL(0) NULL
|    |    |    |    ['NAME'] = String(11) "Chad Riddle"
|    |    |    |    ['CURRENCYPREFIX'] = String(1) "$"
|    |    |    |    ['CURRENCYSUFFIX'] = String(4) " USD"
|    |    |    |    ['FRAUDDATA'] = NULL(0) NULL
|    |    |    |    ['LINEITEMS5'] => Array (1)
|    |    |    |    (
|    |    |    |    |    ['LINEITEM6'] => Array (8)
|    |    |    |    |    (
|    |    |    |    |    |    ['TYPE'] = String(7) "product"
|    |    |    |    |    |    ['RELID'] = String(3) "486"
|    |    |    |    |    |    ['PRODUCTTYPE'] = String(21) "Other Product/Service"
|    |    |    |    |    |    ['PRODUCT'] = String(46) "SecureLive Addons - SecureLive Addon Domain 10"
|    |    |    |    |    |    ['DOMAIN'] = String(14) "blestatest.com"
|    |    |    |    |    |    ['BILLINGCYCLE'] = String(7) "Monthly"
|    |    |    |    |    |    ['AMOUNT'] = String(9) "$4.00 USD"
|    |    |    |    |    |    ['STATUS'] = String(6) "Active"
|    |    |    |    |    )
|    |    |    |    )
|    |    |    )
|    |    |    ['ORDER7'] => Array (26)
|    |    |    (
|    |    |    |    ['ID'] = String(3) "187"
|    |    |    |    ['ORDERNUM'] = String(10) "9493314051"
|    |    |    |    ['USERID'] = String(2) "66"
|    |    |    |    ['CONTACTID'] = String(1) "0"
|    |    |    |    ['DATE'] = String(19) "2013-12-31 15:58:48"
|    |    |    |    ['NAMESERVERS'] = NULL(0) NULL
|    |    |    |    ['TRANSFERSECRET'] = NULL(0) NULL
|    |    |    |    ['RENEWALS'] = NULL(0) NULL
|    |    |    |    ['PROMOCODE'] = NULL(0) NULL
|    |    |    |    ['PROMOTYPE'] = NULL(0) NULL
|    |    |    |    ['PROMOVALUE'] = NULL(0) NULL
|    |    |    |    ['ORDERDATA'] = String(6) "a:0:{}"
|    |    |    |    ['AMOUNT'] = String(4) "4.00"
|    |    |    |    ['PAYMENTMETHOD'] = String(9) "authorize"
|    |    |    |    ['INVOICEID'] = String(1) "0"
|    |    |    |    ['STATUS'] = String(6) "Active"
|    |    |    |    ['IPADDRESS'] = String(12) "64.50.180.53"
|    |    |    |    ['FRAUDMODULE'] = NULL(0) NULL
|    |    |    |    ['FRAUDOUTPUT'] = NULL(0) NULL
|    |    |    |    ['NOTES'] = NULL(0) NULL
|    |    |    |    ['PAYMENTMETHODNAME'] = String(11) "Credit Card"
|    |    |    |    ['PAYMENTSTATUS'] = NULL(0) NULL
|    |    |    |    ['NAME'] = String(11) "Chad Riddle"
|    |    |    |    ['CURRENCYPREFIX'] = String(1) "$"
|    |    |    |    ['CURRENCYSUFFIX'] = String(4) " USD"
|    |    |    |    ['FRAUDDATA'] = NULL(0) NULL
|    |    |    )
|    |    )
|    )
)
```

Basically what I am trying to get is the order id, which is basically $array['WHMCSAPI']['ORDERS']['ORDER']['ID'] by searching for the domain name, which is $array['WHMCSAPI']['ORDERS']['ORDER']['LINEITEMS']['LINEITEM']['DOMAIN']

Notice that the 'ORDER' KEY changes, so does the 'LINEITEMS' and 'LINEITEM'.

So if I was to search for jbrowns.com, it would pull back order number 189, or if I was searching for blestatest it would pull back id 188.

I have tried array_walk, array_search and many pre-built functions that did not give me the information I needed. Has anyone come across this situation.

This is basically for WHMCS, this is the getorders API function. If one of my customers needs to cancel their service from the website, the API function 'deleteorder' requires the orderid, and the only way I can get the order id is by searching for the domain they would like to cancel.

Any assistance would be very helpful.

Thanks,
Jeff

Comment: Can you provide the PHP code that declares the array?

Comment: The code that is building the array is coming from an API using cURL from WHMCS. Although I would be happy to build the array for you.

Comment: Here is the array: http://pastebin.com/6CqYuGzu Thanks for looking

Comment: That array declaration does not have the LINEITEM(S) arrays.

Comment: My bad, I had manually deleted the items inside WHMCS because it was trying to charge the customer for them. I recreated the items, and created a new PasteBin: http://pastebin.com/dJsr5rG4 Thanks for looking.

Comment: What tool did you use to create the PHP array declaration?  Or did you go through the tedious process of declaring it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you.  Just plug in your array and the domain you are looking for and assign to a variable.

```
<?php

function getOrderID($searchfor, $input_array){
    foreach($input_array['WHMCSAPI']['ORDERS'] as $orderskey => $ordersvalue){

        foreach($ordersvalue as $orderkey => $ordervalue){

            if(preg_match("/LINEITEMS[1-9]*/i", $orderkey, $match)){

                foreach($ordervalue as $key => $value){        

                   if($value['DOMAIN'] == $searchfor){
                       $orderid = $input_array['WHMCSAPI']['ORDERS'][$orderskey]['ID']."<br/>";
                   }

                }

             }
         }
    }

    if(isset($orderid)){
         return $orderid;
    }else{
         return "Domain not found";
    }

}


$id = getOrderID("blestatest.com", $array);

echo $id;

?>
```

Comment: Worked like a champ! Send me a paypal address and I will buy you a beer! My email is jeff DOT brown AT securelive DOT com -- THANKS AGAIN!

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

```
<?php
$domain = "www.your-domain.com";
$order_id = 0;
$found = FALSE;

if (!$found) {
    foreach ($array as $arr) {
        foreach ($arr['ORDERS'] as $ords) {
            foreach($ords['ORDER'] as $ord) {
                $order_id = $ord['ID'];
                foreach($ord['LINEITEMS'] as $litems) {
                    foreach($litems['LINEITEM'] as $litem) {
                        if ($litem['DOMAIN'] == $domain) {
                            $found = TRUE;
                            break 5;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, although I did have that similar already done, the problem is this... Notice the ORDER and the LINEITEM. Depending on the number of orders, there is a number after it. Some customers have over 2,000 orders, so there are numbers like LINEITEM2351 etc.

Comment: The only thing I can think of using that method would be to count the number of ORDERS and cycle through each one looking for the next digit until it hits the total count of them, although I think that is very bad idea in programming. What is shocking to me is, I wouldn't think this is that difficult from a program that is as popular as WHMCS.

Comment: oh i didn't notice that the number of orders would go this much higher. anyway you found the solution, have a nice day :)